# Preview on Device with Data JSON throws exception

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-presentation-language

Testing a simple Alexa skill in Authoring tool, with just one text box getting data from "Data JSON" tab throws an exception on doing preview on device. However same works fine when I hard code data directly in the render template.

I have a simple render document with just one text type. And a data JSON having just one property which binds with the text type. It renders fine on the Authoring tool simulator. However, it throws two errors on doing preview on device -
1. There was an error pushing the template to the device.
2. JSON errors found for layout and data integration. Fix errors and view on device again.

[image]

If I remove the binding and add the text right in the render document, preview works.

Also, default samples available on authoring tool works like a charm on both simulator and preview on device.

Render document
`{
  "type": "APL",
  "version": "1.0",
  "theme": "dark",
  "mainTemplate": {
    "parameters": [
      "payload"
    ],
    "item": [
      {
        "type": "Text",
        "color": "#FFFFFF",
        "text": "${payload.textTitle}"
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Data JSON
`{
  "textTitle": "Hello how are you"
}`

I think I am missing something very basic. This simple example should have worked.

I am previewing it on Echo Show 2nd generation

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around APL and run into this same issue. It seems that the `datasource` must contain objects, not primitives. So `${payload.titleText}` fails some kind of schema check before sending to the device. And when you put it into an object under the `datasource`, e.g. `${payload.title.text}`, no errors!

The following appears to work for me:

```
 {
  "type": "APL",
  "version": "1.0",
  "theme": "dark",
  "mainTemplate": {
    "parameters": [
      "payload"
    ],
    "item": [
      {
        "type": "Text",
        "color": "#FFFFFF",
        "text": "${payload.title.text}"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and this data:

```
{
  "title": { "text": "Hello how are you" }
}
```

Comment: You are right, I am doing that in my projects. I hope someone from Alexa team officially accept this issue and fix it.